# Can Twilio pass multiple caller IDs?

Tags: twilio

In my app, a call originates with a customer calling an office number, and the office number forwarding to a Twilio number that I assign. Can Twilio pass to me both the originating number and the office number from which it was forwarded (and distinguish between the two)?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest checking the `ForwardedFrom` parameter that Twilio includes in the HTTP request to your Voice Request URL.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#synchronous-request-parameters

just know that its not perfect because not every carrier passes the originating number to us when they forward the call.

Hope that helps.